# Javascript delay with while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, settimeout

the site is [here](http://tradekart.edicypages.com) I'm trying to create an animated button by moving the position of the background using Javascript when the user clicks the button. However, instead of slowly scrolling, the button jumps to the end of the loop. Here's the code:

```
var x=1, y=0, z=1;

function animate () {
    document.getElementById("switch").style.backgroundPosition = y + 'px 0px';
}

function toggle() {
    // check if button is on
    if (x==1) {
        //As long as image is not yet in place, move the background
        while (y>-37) {
            //Delay each move by 500 and increase the delay
            setTimeout("animate()",500*z);
            --y;++z;
        }
        --x;
        //reset increasing timer
        z=1;
    }
    // check if button is off
    else if (x==0) {
        //As long as image is not yet in place, move the background
        while (y<0) {
            //Delay each move by 500 and increase the delay
            setTimeout("animate()",500*z);
            ++y;++z;
        }
        ++x;
        //reset increasing timer
        z=1;
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to fix. Thanks!

Comment: When the `animate()` is called the first time (by `setTimeout`), the `while` loop already finished and `y` will have "end value" (e.g. `-37`). If you provide a simplified http://jsfiddle.net example, I would be more inclined to help you ;) But the basic idea would be to not start the timeouts all at once but each call creates a new timeout... something like that.

Comment: Ok, signing up for jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UrBestFriend/26PfR/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wambotron/8JhkU/ Try something like this. BTW your timeout earlier would've made this animation excruciatingly slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
var on = true,
    sw = document.getElementById("switch"),
    stop, y = 0,
    dir, to;

function animate() {
    sw.style.backgroundPosition = y + 'px 0px';
    y += dir;
    if (y != stop) {
        to = setTimeout(animate,25);
    }
}

function toggle() {
    if (to) {
        clearTimeout(to);
    }
    if (on) {
        dir = -1;
        stop = -38;
    }
    else {
        dir = 1;
        stop = 2;

    }
    to = setTimeout(animate, 25);
    on = !on;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/26PfR/4/)

Don't know if it is the best way though.

Note: You either have to run the code in the `body.onload` event handler or put it at the bottom of the page.

You can also try to play with the step size and the timeout time.... <del>there was something else I wanted to say, but I forgot ;)</del>

Another note: You should always use expressive variable names. E.g. It was not clear that `x` is used as a boolean indicator (at least not if you only have a quick lock at it).

Comment: Definitely follow the advice on var names.

Comment: Thanks! I switched y += dir; and sw.style.backgroundPosition = y + 'px 0px'; position so that there won't be an initial bounce when the function is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) function doesn't pause, it just arranges to execute the function (its first argument) after the specified delay and then immediately returns. So, launching a whole bunch of timeouts isn't that useful. You want the `setTimeout` callback to call `setTimeout` to start another timer. And you can use a function rather than a string as the first argument to `setTimeout`.

Comment: This is only part of the problem as the the timeout gets increased in every iteration. So would the function that is called in `setTimeout` not depend on a variable that is modified in the loop it would work...

Comment: @Felix: True but you got your jsfiddle and sorted it all out before I got back here. So, +1 for you.